# Simplest examples demonstrating the need for nominal type role in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to understand what determines whether a type parameter must be nominal.

While GADTs and type familes seem different in the sense they are not "simple containers" as their instance definitions can "look at" their parameters, can simple types have obvious need for nominal parameters, like Set?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Should you be able to coerce?

```
 coerce :: Coercible a b => F a -> F b
```

If not, then the argument of `F` should be nominal.

In the case of [`Set`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.11.0/docs/Data-Set.html#t:Set) its first role is nominal

```
type role Set nominal
```

because we don't want

```
coerce :: Set Int -> Set ReversedInt
```

because `newtype ReversedInt = RevInt Int deriving (Eq, Ord) via Data.Ord.Down Int` has a completely different `Ord` than `Int` and the internal structure of `Set` depends on the ordering of its elements. Same for [`Map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.11.0/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#t:Map)

```
type role Map nominal representational
```

---

For a GADT like

```
data F :: Type -> Type where
  FInt :: F Int
```

we have a single inhabitant, so we don't want to allow

```
coerce :: F Int -> F ReversedInt
```

So, GHC infers `type role F nominal`.